# Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage

Tags: java, docker, cucumber, testcontainers

I am using `testcontainers` for the integration test where I create a container.
But its failing with following error:

```
Step failed
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
.....
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=<my-docker-image>:latest, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1282)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:616)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:321)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:312)
....
```

By looking at the error it looks like it is not able to find the docker image.
But, I do have the image in local, I checked by comparing character by character.

I debugged it and at [this](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/1.15.2/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/GenericContainer.java#L1284) line, I check the image has all the right value but for some reason its throwing an exception instead of returning the right value.

Any idea how can this be fixed?

Versions:
testcontainers : [1.15.0-rc2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.15.0-rc2)
Docker version : 3.1.0, Engine: 20.10.2

**Adding debug log**(see how `this.image.getImage()` name gets the name but other two **fails**):

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, that your image has `latest` tag as well? I expect that you have changed the part from <my-docker-image> output log.

Comment: I am absolutely sure, I changed it because it had my company name. I checked with another engineer the name and tag of image, so I am dead sure name is same :(

Comment: I'd recommend to add a breakpoint at the `org.testcontainers.images.AbstractImagePullPolicy.shouldPull()` method start and debug more. Looks like for some reason Tescontainers does not see, that the image is already available in the local cache.

Answer (score 1):

`.testcontainer.properties` in my `$HOME` directory fixed the issue for me.
This file is used to override properties but I am still not sure how that fixes the issue.
I see in my `.gitlab.yml` that what we do and just imitated that in my local, that solved the issue.

Comment: Are you getting the same error ? Can you post your err msg?

Comment: so it got fixed?

Comment: yes it got fixed.it fixed automtically that is my concern

Answer (score 1):

For some it might help to update the version of testcontainers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).